# Passing data from an adapter over a dialog to a activity

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am attempting to pass data from my adapter to an activity with a dialog between them.

My current data flow is

RecyclerAdapter --> Confirmation Activity --> Chat Activity

What I want

RecyclerAdapter --> Custom Dialog --> Chat Activity

[image: Image describing data flow]

previously in my on click, I just had an intent to carry it over to the confirmation activity then to the chat activity but I am unable to do that now. I read on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15466673/how-to-send-data-through-intent-in-android-without-opening-another-activity) about using shared preferences but was unable to successfully implement it so I am wondering if there is a better way to go about it if i am missing any information pleas let me know and i will update it

adapter

```
    public void openDialog(){

    FragmentManager manager = ((AppCompatActivity)mContext).getSupportFragmentManager();

    Confirmation_Dialog confirmation_dialog = new Confirmation_Dialog();
    confirmation_dialog.show(manager, "example dialog");



}
```

dialog

```
    @Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_dialog, null);

    builder.setView(view)

            .setTitle("Are You Sure");


            mYesBtn = view.findViewById(R.id.yes_button_dialog);
            mNoBtn = view.findViewById(R.id.no_button_dialog);

            mYesBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "it worked YES!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            mNoBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    dismiss();
                }
            });


    return builder.create();

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of having the dialog in a separate file I just moved it into the adapter class

Comment: Despite did not be beautiful for organization of code, works fine...

Answer (score 0):

Just use bundle to pass data to the new Activity.

In the adapter

```
String value="Hello world";
Intent i = new Intent(context, NewActivity.class);    
i.putExtra("key",value);
startActivity(i);
```

Then in the new Activity, retrieve those values:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    String value = extras.getString("key");
    //The key argument here must match that used in the other activity
}
```

Comment: How do I go about using an intent for my use case because in the on click to bring up the dialog if I use an intent with it the app will just launch the new activity and dismiss the dialog rendering the dialog pointless

Comment: this intent is to be prepared when YES is clicked.

Comment: But yes is clicked in the confirmation dialog class not the adapter so the data has to somehow get to the dialog class

Comment: the dialog class is from the adapter, isntn it?
Inside adapter's onclick action you must have the item position. Then when YES is clicked on the dialog just user the item position to retrieve the item and put it inside the intent.

Comment: No, the dialog is in its own separate file that's what's giving me all the issues

Answer (score 0):

Your dialog is `FragmentDialog`, you can use `setArguments` method to pass argument.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use shared pref to pass data, shared pref is more like saving data in the phone for future reference. In this case (like @average_developer suggested) use `Intent Bundles` to pass data to the targeted activity.

I think in your case, you have to use (code below) to actually get some information to identify which chat it will be created in the following activity.

```
 @Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int pos, long l) {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, ProductActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("item_id", manager.getItemIdAtIndex(pos));
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Comment: How do I go about using an intent for my use case because in the on click to bring up the dialog if I use an intent with it the app will just launch the new activity and dismiss the dialog rendering the dialog pointless

Comment: Ok, so according to your use case: 

What I want:
RecyclerAdapter --> Custom Dialog --> Chat Activity

What you need to do:
Put the intent into the Custom Dialog, im sure in the custom dialog there is like a "Ok" button and a "Cancel/No" Button, so in the "Ok" button, do your logic code and then place an intent into it when it is clicked. 

After which, your concern would be "Which chat did user clicked in the previous activity", so there comes in play the bundles you passed along with the intent. Receive the bundle and extract information and the do your logic to generate the chat

Comment: The adapter and dialog and two separate files so i need to be able to get the data to the dialog file i do not have an intent that triggers the dialog

Comment: If i recalled correctly, there's sort of onitemclick in the adapter, do read up about it, and then place your dialog code in it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create adapter click event in to activity class and make interface in to your adapter like below in your adapter do like:

```
 onCircularsClick _oncircularClick;

    public interface onCircularsClick {

        public void _onCircularClick(Circular.TableBean bean);
    }
```

your adapter constructor

```
 public CircularListAdapter(Context ctx,  onCircularsClick __oncircularClick) {
        this.ctx = ctx;


        this._oncircularClick = __oncircularClick;

    }
```

and  set click like

```
viewHolder.lin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                _oncircularClick._onCircularClick(list.get(i));//data that you want to pass when click fires
            }
        });
```

and while setting adapter from your activity you can get this click event over there so can write code for click (open dialog ) in to activity class